# I want to archive actions made by a button but get an error from my combo box and don't know why

Tags: excel, list, sorting, combobox, archive

So I made an excel sheet with a button to add/remove stock and add a new line if the stock you entered isn't in the system yet. This was done through a combo box. I have a line which pastes the combo box value (for when a new item is added) and essentially duplicated this in another cell but for some reason it's sending me an application or object error.

```
    Dim C As Range
       With lstRng
        Set C = .Find(cbxList.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If C Is Nothing Then
            Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = cbxList.Value #this one works and adds to the end of my stock list
            Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = tbxStock.Value
            Range("aa65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Stock in"
            Range("ab65536").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Value = cbxList.Value
            Range("ac65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = tbxStock.Value
            Range("ad65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = txtDate.Value
            Range("ae65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = txtRequest.Value
            Range("af65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = txtAllocate.Value
            Range("ag65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = txtReason.Value
            Me.cbxList.Value = ""
            Me.tbxStock.Value = ""
            Me.txtDate.Value = ""
            Me.txtRequest.Value = ""
            Me.txtAllocate.Value = ""
            Me.txtReason.Value = ""
        ElseIf Not C Is Nothing Then
            C.Offset(0, 1).Value = C.Offset(0, 1).Value + tbxStock.Value
            Range("aa65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Stock in"
            Range("ab65536").End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0).Value = cbxList.Value #the error is here for this piece. If I mouse over the "cbxList.Value" it shows me the value I entered and if I mouse over the previous bit it gives me - = <Application-defined or Object-defined error>
            Range("ac65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = tbxStock.Value
            Range("ad65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = txtDate.Value
            Range("ae65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = txtRequest.Value
            Range("af65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = txtAllocate.Value
            Range("ag65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = txtReason.Value
        End If
    End With
    Me.cbxList.Value = ""
    Me.tbxStock.Value = ""
    Me.txtDate.Value = ""
    Me.txtRequest.Value = ""
    Me.txtAllocate.Value = ""
    Me.txtReason.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason you have a digit "1" rather than a letter "l" in `End(x1Up)`. Only in that line!

Comment: You are my hero, when looking at it in VBA it was identical looking it's not until you said that and I looked on google that I realised it was different. I have just tried it and it worked! Thank you!!!!

Comment: As it happens it's not the first time this query has come up.